# Are there English affixes for left/right?

Tags: affixes

Is there an affix that means left (right)? E.g. Imagine it was the prefix lef-. We'd be able to generate the following words.

- lefcars (cars in which the steering wheel is on the left-hand side)
- leffoils ([foils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_%28fencing%29) with the grip set-up for a left-hander)
- lefpoliticians (politicians associated with the political left)

etc.

Comment: The second one is definitely "left-handed". A left-handed pair of scissors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd usually go for [***levo*** and ***dextro***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrorotation_and_levorotation) in contexts involving "coinages", etc. Both have Latin roots (as does [*sinistr(o)*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/sinistro)=left) - offhand I don't know any corresponding *Greek* equivalents.

Note that ***levo*** may also appear as [***laevo, lævo, lev***.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/levo-) But these pairings are *always* concerned with *literal* ["handedness"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/handedness), so they wouldn't be suitable where the *left/right* distinction is already *figurative*, such as the political spectrum.

Comment: My issue with this is that dextro- means *clockwise*, not right. Clockwise involves movement to the right when the hand is at 12 o'clock, and movement to the left when the hand is at 6 o'clock. So "clockwise" really has nothing to do with "right."

Comment: @user18921 Balderdash. When you circle something clockwise or deasil, your right side is towards the thing in question; and the mnemonic for *right-hand* screw-threads is "righty tighty, lefty loosey." Plus of course *dexter* is Latin for right. Dextro- as clockwise *derives* from dextro- as *right.*

Comment: @user18921: What Brian said. I think you've probably got more of an issue with the part of your thinking which seems to assume the *political* left/right specturm is a relevant usage here. If you don't know where that comes from, [read this](http://politicsreport.com/article/what-origin-political-left-and-right) *During the French Revolution, the representatives who sat on the right side of the Legislative Assembly were supporters of the aristocracy and the monarchy. Those on the left opposed the old order and supported the interests of the bourgeoisie or rising merchant class.*

Comment: _Dextro-_ means ‘right’, not ‘clockwise’. Dextrorphan and levorphanol, for example, are not thus named because they are orphaned in any clockwise or anticlockwise manner, but because they are orphaned on the right and left, respectively.

Comment: If what Janus says is correct then its irrelevant, but what do you mean when you say: "When you circle something clockwise or deasil, your right side is towards the thing in question."

Comment: @Janus: Given the etymology or *levo* and *dextro*, I don't really understand OP's nit-picking here. But I did deliberately include my first link because Google's first result for **prefix left right** was to [Wikipedia's article on ***dextrorotation and levorotation***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrorotation_and_levorotation), and I am aware that the "direction of spirals/rotations" is a common context for this prefixe pair.

Comment: @user18921 He means that if you are walking around something (or someone) clockwise, then that thing/person (who's in the middle of the circle your paces draw) will always be on your right-hand side. Clockwise is always rightwise seen from the centre of the circle.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to these matters of chirality, besides the already mentioned *dextro-* for right, for which the OED gives these examples:

> ***dextrogyre*** /ˈdɛkstrəʊdʒaɪə(r)/ a. L. *gȳrus*, Gr. *γῠρος* circuit, gyrating or circling to the right. *dextroˈgyrate* a. L. *gyrāt-us,* pa. pple. of *gȳrāre* to wheel round, characterized by turning the plane of polarization to the right, as a *dextrogyrate* crystal. ***dextroˈgyrous*** a. = *dextrogyre*. ***dextro-roˈtation***, rotation to the right. ***dextro-ˈrotatory*** a., having or producing rotation to the right; dextrogyrous.

The OED also attests *sinistro-* for left:

> **sinistro-** /ˈsɪnɪstrəʊ/, used as combining form of *sinister*, in the sense ‘on, situated in, directed or turning towards the left’, as ***sinistro-cerebral***, ***-gyrate, -gyric*** adjs.; ***sinistro-sacrad*** adv.
>
> - 1803 J. Barclay *New Anat. Nomencl*. 174 ― The position of the heart in the thorax;··we may say its direction from the mesial plane is sinistrad and sacrad, or sinistro-sacrad.
> - 1885 *Proc. Soc. Psychol. Research* III. 43 ― The replacement of some sinistro-cerebral by some dextro-cerebral centre of sight or speech.
> - 1887 *Amer. Jrnl. Psychol*. I. 194 ― All movements of the hand··from right to left are sinistrogyric.
> - 1898 *Daily Graphic* 16 Feb. 9/4 ― The writing··was sinistrogyrate, or centrifugal.

I for one will definitely be incorporating *sinistrogyrate* into my daily discourse, giving all three of *counterclockwise, anticlockwise*, and *widdershins* a well-deserved rest. :)